# Write function with dynamic variables to get its Hessian matrix using syms, f, and hessian

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, hessian-matrix

My problem has 60 variables (`x1` to `x60`) and here is the function:

```
f=(x1+x2+x3)*x1+(x2+x3+x4)*x2+...+(x58+x59+x60)*x58
```

I want to get the Hessian matrix of the function `f`. However, because there are so many variables, I don't want to write them one by one for `syms` and `f`.

I know I can manually calculate the Hessian matrix of the function `f` as the function is not too difficult. However, I occasionally need to change the form of the function, such as changing the function to (increase the number of variables in the brackets):

```
f=(x1+x2+x3+x4)*x1+(x2+x3+x4+x5)*x2+...+(x57+x58+x59+x60)*x57
```

Therefore, I don't want to manually compute the Hessian matrix of function `f` as long as the function form changes. Is there any easier way to use `syms` to write `f` with these 60 variables in MATLAB so that I can use `hessian` to get the Hessian matrix of `f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, given the regular and simple nature of the function `f` described, your Hessian has a defined structure that can be directly calculated numerically. Like this, for example:

```
n = 60; % number of variables
b = 3;  % number of terms in parentheses
h = diag(2+zeros(n,1));
for i = 1:b-1
    d = diag(ones(n-i,1),i);
    h = h+d+d.';
end
h(n-b+2:n,n-b+2:n) = 0
```

This can be done without a `for` loop via something like this:

```
n = 60; % number of variables
b = 3;  % number of terms in parentheses
h = full(spdiags(repmat(ones(n,1),1,2*b-1),1-b:b-1,n,n)+speye(n));
h(n-b+2:n,n-b+2:n) = 0
```

Symbolically, you can create a vector of variables with [`sym`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) to create your function and calculate the Hessian like this:

```
n = 60; % number of variables
b = 3;  % number of terms in parentheses
x = sym('x',[n 1]); % vector of variables
f = 0;
for i = 1:n-b+1
    f = f+sum(x(i:i+b-1))*x(i);
end
h = hessian(f,x)
```

It's possible to remove the `for` loops, but there won't be much performance benefit.

Comment: Thank you Horchler very much for providing different options to address my question! The codes are what I need. BTW, thank you for the grammar editing :-)

Comment: Hi Horchler, I met an error when using the symbolical way. It was okay to construct the symbolic variables and the function f. However, when implement h=hessian(f,x), there is always an error: "Error using sym/subsindex (line 737)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are
symbolic variables and the body of the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input
must be numeric, logical, or ':'." Do you know why?

Comment: @NaomiLi: What `version` of MATLAB are you using? Are you using exactly the code above in my answer?

Comment: Yep, I am using Matlab R2015b. I don't know why but the error always come; however, when I tried to use jacobian(gradient(f,x),x), it works without error.